# After torch.load the performance decreases dramatically and after evaluate it increases

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I got a weird bug. This is my model.

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feat_dim, num_classes):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.model_resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained=False)
        num_ftrs = self.model_resnet.fc.in_features
        self.model_resnet.fc = nn.Identity()
        
        self.head1 = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_ftrs),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.Linear(num_ftrs, feat_dim)
            )
        
        self.head2 = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        self.eps=self.eps+1
        x = self.model_resnet(x)
        feat = F.normalize(self.head1(x), dim=1)
        classes = self.head2(x)
        
        return feat,classes
```

The following code is for saving and loading

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(),"./test.pth")
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("test.pth"))
```

Then I trained it and saved weights with test accuracy 0.95. Next time I load it and test something. It is like random guessing and accuracy is near to 0.

After I evaluate it with the whole test set. The test accuracy return to 0.8 but still lose performance.

I checked model.state_dict() the weights are the same before and after evaluating the whole test set.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: You should also share the code you use to save and load. Did you partition the dataset in a training, evaluation and validation data sets? Perhaps, your model is overfitting on the training dataset. When you validate on different data in the validation dataset, then the accuracy drop can be explained by this overfitting. If this is the case, you can try training for less epochs or increase the amount of training data or other measures to make you network generalize better.

Comment: I mean the accuracy decrease for both train and test set after loading the weights. After I loaded it without doing anything just testing a single image, it gave me the random output. After I evaluate it, I can get some correct outputs.

Answer (score 0):

After the whole day of debugging, finally I found the reason. After I reloaded the model I did not set model.eval() and did some calculations.